# How to solve "The specified class doesn't exists in given namespace" error?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, visual-studio-2017

1. I tried clean - build - rebuild.
2. Also deleting Shadowcache and rebuilding.
   (Visual studio 2017 community)

If anyone knows a way to get rid of this error, please answer.

Comment: We could help you, if you will help us. Give more details, please - paste a part of code which cause an error

Comment: The error said all. Your class in not inside the given namespace. Please post class definition along with namespace name.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot for the concern @both.

I found the solution.

The solution is to try different configurations in the project properties.
E.g., 1. changing "Any CPU" to "x86" > build solution
Then change x86 to x64 > Rebuild solution

Close and Reopen VS

2. Delete Shadowcache in designer file > close and Reopen VS